# Symfony2 Form Type and DropDown Lists

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

## **Scenario**

I have a form type that I use both for creation or edit of mine entities. These entities have some kind of relationship with other entities in a **x-to-many** fashion. That means that - relatively to save action -my dropdown list will be populated with list of constrained entities.

Suppose that - in form - whe have something like this:

Principal Entity: MiniCooper
List of Accessories
Product 1: [list of input properties that user can insert and save directly with this form]
Product 2: [list of input properties that user can insert and save directly with this form]
.....
Product *n*: [list of input properties that user can insert and save directly with this form]

Where Product[1,2,....,n] are the "many" side of relationship (consider "principal entity" the "x" side of relationship; it doesn't matter for our example if, actually, this should be an n-to-m relationship) and suppose that these related entities are "automatically" assigned to my principal entity on creation of "principal entity" itself.

When I render my form - through an entity type - I'll obtain that Product 1 , Product 2 , .... , Product N will be render as dropdown lists with the corrisponding element selected. 
But..... I don't want this behaviour. I'll prefer that they could be some kind of "label" or something like that (So no one can change the selection and produce multi-assignment of the same "Product"). How can I write my entity type - now these fields are "entity" typed - to obtain this?

Moreover, have I to use mandatorily the Data Transformer ??

## Screenshot

[image: immagine]

As you can see from screenshot, all dropdownlist (apart "price type") shouldn't be dropdown (i know that I can make one-value dropdown but i don't want them).
Hope this image will help you to understand better my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll prefer that they could be some kind of "label" or something like that (So no one can change the selection and produce multi-assignment of the same "Product")

From what you describe it sounds as though you want to display the data, rather than provide a form to edit it (that is, you want to list the entity and its accessories on the page).

The way to tackle this is to avoid forms altogether, and just make the entities available in the view and render the information directly.

Alternatively if you are attempting to represent in a form 'multiple choice' amongst related items in a (for simplicity's sake) 1-to-many relationship, the 'expanded' and 'multiple' options for the 'entity' form field type should do what you want.

If neither of these is the answer, then it'll be because I'm struggling to grasp the question :).

Comment: When I say (checkbox), actually, I mean some list of property for that product. So, I want to display "principal entity" along its association and these associations could be directly modified in the same page (so, in simple terms, I want that we can assign some values to the properties of these associations).